# How to display a date_time field in jinja2 template? (flask)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

I have a form with these two values (ndb is the Google App Engine [ndb model](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass)):

model:

```
class Appointment(model.Base):
    start_time = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
    end_time = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
```

form (using wtforms):

```
class AppointmentUpdateForm(wtf.Form):
    start_time = wtforms.DateField('Start at', [wtforms.validators.required()])
    end_time = wtforms.DateField('End at', [wtforms.validators.required()])
```

And in the jinja2 template I have:

```
  {{forms.date_field(form.start_time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}}
  {{forms.date_field(form.end_time)}}
```

I want to display the form inputs as time widget but it looks like a date field. I think wtforms has a date_time field but how can I implement that?

Comment: Do you mean wtforms.DateTimeField doesn't do what you want?

Comment: I want to display and render it in a template correctly

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. Your form class is using DateField, not DateTimeField.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display a datetime widget you need to create a custom widget. when defining the form
pass the widget for it with your own widget

To the widget, take a look at this example:

https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/flask_appbuilder/fieldwidgets.py#L5

Then define the form like this:

```
class AppointmentUpdateForm(wtf.Form):
    start_time = wtforms.DateField('Start at', [wtforms.validators.required()], widget=DatePickerWidget())
    end_time = wtforms.DateField('End at', [wtforms.validators.required()], widget=DatePickerWidget())
```

Remember this is using bootstrap Datetime picker so you have to include the CSS and js.